# Passing data to Vue child component without re-mounting it

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js

I have a page that includes some audio visualization that's being done within a component. The component is only for displaying stuff, the audio logic is done in the parent.
I'll keep this part short, since my problem is more general, but basically I'm passing the AnalyserNode to the child to poll the realtime frequency analysis from within my Three.js render-loop in the child (WorkletModule).

So in my parent I have something like this:

```
<template>
    ...
    <WorkletModule
      :analyser="analyser"
      :key="componentKey"
    />
    ...
</template>

...

data() {
    return {
      componentKey: 0,
      analyser: null,
    };

methods: {
     startRecording() {
      this.componentKey++
      ..

      this.analyser = audioContext.createAnalyser();
      ..
     }
}
```

while my *WorkletModule.vue* looks like this:

```
  props: {
    analyser: {
      type: AnalyserNode
    },
  },

  mounted() {
      //initialize graphics, etc..
  }

//in the render loop I need to do something like this:
this.analyser.getByteFrequencyData(soundData);
```

Now if I use it like above, it does actually work, however, every call to *startRecording()* causes the WorkletModule to re-mount, creating a hick-up and emptying the canvas of the WorkletModule.

If I remove the *":key="componentKey"* it doesn't get updated, which means that the reference to the analyzer in the WorkletModule/prop always stays null, which is obviously not what I want.
Is there a way to pass the analyzer object in another form than a prop?

Basically I need the analyzer value in every frame of the render-loop. I could not pass it as a prop but rather emit an event from the render loop of the WorkletModule that in turn gets the parent to send the current values back to the child via another event. That doesn't seem like a very elegant thing though, so I guess there's a better way.

Comment: The key issue here is `...the reference to the analyser in the WorkletModule/prop always stays null`. Props are reactive, so the WorkletModule should always have access to the analyser prop when updated in parent once you call startRecording. Can you post your full WorkletModule component code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm really puzzled by this:

> If I remove the ":key="componentKey" it doesn't get updated, which means that **the reference to the analyser in the WorkletModule/prop always stays null**

This is not supposed to happen since props are updated without re-rendering by default. Of course, if you use a key, the component is fully destroyed and recreated on every key update.

You could listen to your props update by using a watcher.

In the example below, I pass a prop to a children component, from null to a number. The component is only rendered once and the prop is updated as expected. I only added a watcher to track every update of the said prop and give me the possibility to add any logic from that. You could try to do that in order to understand if the prop is really never updated or maybe your implementation lacks something (and you didn't show us the malicious bit of code that drives you into thinking it's not updated).

```js
const test = Vue.component("test", {
  props: ["prop1"],
  methods: {
    getProp() {
      console.log(this.prop1);
    }
  },
  created() {
    console.log("created"); // only called once
    setInterval(this.getProp, 2000);
  },
  watch: {
    prop1(newVal, oldVal) {
      console.log("watcher:", newVal, oldVal);
      // do something
    }
  },
  template: "<div>test</div>"
});

new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  components: {
    test
  },
  data: {
    toProp: null
  },
  methods: {
    setProp() {
      this.toProp = new Date().valueOf();
    }
  },
  created() {
    setInterval(this.setProp, 6000);
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <test :prop1="toProp" />
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your effort! After seeing it work in theory I did some more debugging and realized the analyzer only returns null in the first couple of frames of the render loop (due to the audio code being async). Of course it already crashed by then so I didn't see it pick up eventually. Doing `if(this.analyser === null) return` on top of the render loop solves the problem for me.